# pthread_create with no arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, pthreads, posix

I want to create a thread with no function arguments but I keep getting errors that are seriously bugging me because I cant get something super simple to work right

Heres my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<array>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

void *showart(NULL);

int main(int argc,  char** argv){
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, showart, NULL);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void *showart(NULL)
{
    std::string text;
    std::ifstream ifs("ascii");
    while(!ifs.eof()) 
    {
      std::getline(ifs,text);
      printf(text.c_str());
    }
}
```

It gives the error:

```
main.cpp:11:50: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your function has to match the `pthread` one; it needs to take and return a `void*`.

Use `void* showart(void*);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Both the declaration and definition for your thread function are incorrect. You can use `NULL` when *calling* it, but the *type* of that parameter, needed for declaration/definition, is `void *`.

Hence you need something like:

```
void *showart(void *);              // declaration
void *showart(void *unused) { ... } // definition
```

---

In other words, this will do the trick:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<array>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

void *showart (void *);

int main (int argc,  char **argv) {
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_create (&thread1, NULL, showart, NULL);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void *showart (void *unused) {
    std::string text;
    std::ifstream ifs("ascii");
    while(!ifs.eof()) {
        std::getline (ifs, text);
        printf ("%s\n", text.c_str());
    }
}
```

Although you should probably consider making your code a little more robust, such as checking the return code from `pthread_create()`, joining to the thread within `main()`, checking to ensure the file exists, and so on.

Comment: You don't need to name `unused` in the definition, which avoids getting an unused warning under some compiler configs.