# C++ invalid conversion from 'pthread_t' to 'pthread_t* {aka long unsigned int}'' to 'pthread_t*

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am new to pthreads,trying to make this code work but i am having problem with creating threads.

I still couldnt understand how to create a pthread with pthread_create() function which is having a struct object(thread),and also i have problems with  exiting from threads.I am trying to create 3 threads in my main,and pass functions to them which are doing some work with the vector.

[pthread_create with no arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193333/pthread-create-with-no-arguments)

I  have checked this question and tried to fix but couldnt

[image]

Comment: Please post the error as actual text, not as an image of text.

Comment: Also why are you using `malloc` instead of `new`? Any specific reason?

Comment: Since you edited the answer into your question the given answers don't make sense.

Comment: You have tagged this OP as C++.  Is there a reason you are not using std::thread?  std::thread is much more convenient than Posix thread.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the signature of both `agency1` and `agency2` to match for the type of function `pthread_create` accepts

```
void* agency1(void*) { ... }
void* agency2(void*) { ... }
```

Also the conversion error is because `pthread_create` receive a pointer to `pthread_t` and you were passing just a value of that type, you need to change it to:

```
at1 = pthread_create(&aT->agencyTread1, NULL, agency1, NULL);
at2 = pthread_create(&aT->agencyTread2, NULL, agency2, NULL);
mt = pthread_create(&mainThread, NULL, mainT, (void *)aT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the other `pthread` functions, which take `pthread_t` by value, `pthread_create` takes a `pthread_t*` (pointer).

You need something like:

```
int errc;
pthread_t mainThread; /*...*/
if ( 0!=(errc=pthread_create(&mainThread, ...))) 
    throw errno_exception(errc); // { errno=errc; perror(0); /*...*/}
```

Comment: @I0veisreal perror's in `stdio.h` (or in `cstdio` as `std::perror`). `man perror` would have told you that. You'll also need `errno.h` for `errno`, or go down the exception route (more idiomatic to C++).

Comment: after adding them still having the same error,even if i do if(mt) {
    cout << "Error - pthread_create() return code for thread 1: " << mt<< endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }      and compile  I am having segmentation fault error

Comment: alright i managed to make yours work but still i am having segmentation fault error